# Google +1 Button not working in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, google-plus-one

Works fine in IE8, IE9, and latest Chrome and Firefox, but can't seem to get it to show up in IE7. This is even with the most basic example of using the script.

Anyone had similar issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1151309

Looks like it's not supported.

Comment: I came to this conclusion on my own during testing, but it was nice to have reassurance that I was right.  They should have learned from facebook, and just used iframe imho; yet, I do like their push to stop supporting dated browsers.

Comment: IE7 is outdated . It should not be supported anymore