# Why isn't a +1 button showing up in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, google-plus

I'm trying to add a +1 button to http://JonathansCorner.com. Works great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, everything except (drumroll please) Internet Exploder <= 8.0. The +1 button doesn't appear at all; there's just a blank space.

The DOCTYPE was originally XHTML 1.0 Frameset; I tried changing to the HTML5 DOCTYPE which I have now, and that didn't help. The JavaScript console does not show any errors.

What does IE not like about what I've done? I include the original button with a JavaScript include, and then make the JavaScript call from the end of the page. The page again is at http://JonathansCorner.com.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218789/google-1-button-not-working-in-ie7

Comment: On that account it should work in IE8. It doesn't.

Comment: Do you see any script error messages in the F12 Developer Tools console?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're including the +1 Button, and a whole bunch of other stuff, using a huge number of document.write() commands in header.js. IE8 may not like that for some reason.

If you put the +1 Button code directly into the page's html do you still observe this issue?

Also, the +1 Button does not support IE6 or IE7 so it will not render in those browsers.

Comment: Agreed with this. Try actually appending the content as a string to the particular parent node as needed. It's a much cleaner method of populating the page using JS.